# Fun to read non-Feynman introductory physics book

Tags: soft-question, resource-recommendations, education

I am  an  almost layman  in  physics,  and  don't  know much in math (only basic  knowledge  upto  trig ), and want  to  learn physics . .

As  I am  completely inexperienced, and considering most  of  the  textbook  in  physics  are  Hallday  Resnic styled  plug  and chug, somewhere  I found  the  suggestion  to  struggle with Feynman. Crazily most  of  the  places  suggested you  would go astray with  Feynman  (I went astray,  It took  me  two  weeks to  partially understand the Gravitational  Energy, probably fourth chapter) unless you  have  a good  intuitive grasp of basic  ideas  in  physics.

Are there  any  good (not pop sci)  introductory physics books? I'm willing  to struggle to get good understanding,  and (there is no cramming exam pressure to rush) and the book should must be fun and  interesting*.

- Measurement by Paul Lockhart is  an excellent  example of  such  book,  but  it  is  in  mathematics - I want in physics.

Comment: What do you want to learn about?

Comment: You will need math to get very far.

Comment: how about checking out videos. like  @mmesser314 said, the language of physics is math. the two are inextricably intertwined

Comment: Physics is like all sciences: it's best learned from those who practice it, already, rather than from books. Lockhart's book is fuzzy wuzzy feelgood nonsense. You can't learn anything from it about anything, maybe expect for how to make money with books that make people feel better about the avoidance of headaches during serious study.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Okay, but atleast there should be some good books that increases the curiosity in physics and makes it fun and challenging. Do you know any of them ? [ I am not asking for pop sci books which "explains" string theory in one hour to a laymen or something like that; I am willing to struggle and get good understanding in return]

Comment: You have the curiosity, already, don't you? If you don't, there is nothing that can make you learn for eight hours a day for eight years in a row, which is what a typical science student does from the day he/she enters university till he/she finishes his/her PhD.

Comment: @CuriousOne: It's ridiculous to believe that this curiosity is innate, and it is also ridiculous that everyone has the same level of physics (or science) curiosity. There is probably something in between that increases the curiosity (my mental model of curiosity may be wrong) (otherwise why a person would do years of single minded effort, as you mentioned) - I just wanted some explicit examples of them.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a good math background. Work your way through elementary calculus. These ideas in calculus were derived FOR physics. Once you can get a good grasp on the principles of calculus physics will come a lot easier. I enjoy watching YouTube videos on these things. A great amount of information for free